# PHP looping through a function before returning value

Tags: php, function

I have simplified this. I have this line of code in a method in a (codeigniter framework) controller:

```
$the_result = $this->loop1($ordered_bookings);
```

And this is is the 'loop1' function:

```
public function loop1($ob, $count=1):array {
    ++$count;
    if($count < 5)
    {
        $this->loop1($ob, $count);
    }
    else
    {
        return array(1, 2, 3);
    }
}
```

What I need to be able to do is loop through loop1 function until certain conditions are met before then returning the results array. Problem is calling the function again at the end of loop1 seems to be returning to the original call, and returning nothing at that (obviously I guess).

If I change the loop1 function to simply this:

```
public function loop1($ob):array {
    return array(1, 2, 3);
}
```

It works perfectly.

I haven't done this sort of PHP work for a long time and the need to declare a returnType itself was new to me. How can I achieve what I'm aiming for here?

Comment: `loop` or `loop1` inside count condition?

Comment: Your structure looks like a recursive function, I don't feel you need recursion here?

Comment: @nice_dev GAH! Sorry, typo. loop should have been loop1. It calls itself again. I have edited the question so it is correct. My apologies.

Comment: @Scuzzy this is a simplified version of the reality, which does a lot more things with much bigger arrays. I do need a recursive function.

Comment: `return $this->loop1(..`. you are missing the `return`

Comment: @nice_dev Oh my WORD that's so simple! Got it working perfectly! WOW! Just goes to show how long it's been! Thank you. Submit it as answer and I'll gladly accept it. Thanks!

Comment: Typos are usually closed on Stackoverflow, so voted to close.

Comment: @nice_dev I don't mind if you close this question, but my omitting of 'return' wasn't a typo - I didn't think it required it as I was calling the function again rather than returning to where it was originally called. If I had googled and found this question answered here, however simple the answer, the problem would've been solved for me. But close it if you must. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function returns the array only when `$count` it reaches 5. However, when it finally returns the array, you do nothing with it. That is why it gives you nothing. If you want to do something with the array, you need to capture it when you call `loop1` inside itself and pass it along with a return like so:

```
public function loop1($ob, $count=1):array {
    ++$count;
    if($count < 5)
    {
        return $this->loop1($ob, $count);
    }
    else
    {
        return array(1, 2, 3);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realise you had to use return if calling the function again. I only thought you needed to use return when returning to the original call. Your explanation solved it for me. Thanks!